how to use Gauss Multiplication Formula for Gamma function?
I asked this question in MSE
I studied Gauss Multiplication Formula which known for $n\in Z^+ \wedge nx\notin Z^-\cup\{0\}$
$$\Gamma(nz)=(2\pi)^{(1-n)/2}n^{nz-(1/2)}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(z+\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
but I didn't understand how to use it for example by putting $z=\frac{1}{2} , n=2$ then
$$ \prod_{k=0}^1\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$
but this don't give a new formula since we can get it by Reflection formula for Gamma function
but if we put $z=\frac{1}{3} , n=4$ then we can find that
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{12}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{3\sqrt[6]{2}}$$
So my question how to find useful values for $n,z$ to find a new formula using Gauss Multiplication Formula?
there are a lot of examples that I didnt understand how to find correct values of $n,z$ for example how to prove
$$ \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{12}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt[4]{3}} \pi^2$$
more complicate formula is
$$ \Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{2}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{5}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{8}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{14}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{17}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{20}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{23}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{26}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{29}{33} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{32}{33} \right) =\frac{85184}{11^{\frac{19}{6}}\sqrt{3}} \pi^6$$

I am not sure exactly what your question is. To get a formula for
$$\Gamma(1/4)^2\Gamma(7/12)\Gamma(11/12)$$
let $n=3$ and $z=1/4$ in the multiplication formula. This gives an expression for
$$\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(7/12)\Gamma(11/12)/\Gamma(3/4).$$
Now use the reflection formula to express $1/\Gamma(3/4)$ in terms of $\Gamma(1/4)$.

Wikipedia has an article on particular values of the Gamma function, with a list of special values and relations, that one can get combining the functional equation, the reflection formula and the multiplication formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function

Also check
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403510

@HjalmarRosengren Im asking how you find that $n=3 , z=1/4$ ? its not easy to find it if $n,z$ are large for example So isn't there a simple way to get $(n,z)$ ?

@Faoler Since the arguments of the gamma function differ by 1/3 it is obvious that we should take n=3. In your second example the arguments differ by 1/11, so we should take n=11. Using the multiplication formula with $z=2/33$, all factors except one $\Gamma(1/3)$ combine to $\Gamma(2/3)$. Then the remaining $\Gamma(1/3)$ combines with $\Gamma(2/3)$ using the reflection formula. One can certainly give more complicated examples (like in the paper by Vidunas that Pietro Majer links to). But the two examples you give are in my opinion completely straight-forward.

@HjalmarRosengren thanks I will try to use this idea
